# Count with different group by used in a select statement

Tags: sql, oracle11g, count

I have a query as shown below

```
select sum(amount)/count(id) from tabel1 where name ='sam';
```

I have a table like this

```
name id transaction_type_id transaction_type
sam   1    23                 direct
sam   1    56                 direct
sam   1     21                indirect
sam   1     34                indirect
```

when I do count(id) am getting answer as '4' but i want it to be '2' because it have 2 transaction_type as 'direct and indirect'.please help me .

Thanks

Comment: `count(distinct transaction_type)`?

Comment: What is `amount` column ? where did it came from?

Comment: Please show your expected results. I dont understand " i want it to be '2' because it have 2 transaction_type". Do you want to count distinct transaction types? Or are you talking about the avarage number of IDs per transaction type? Or what else? Would it be another "count" if there were three entries for 'direct' instead of two?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select sum(amount)/count(distinct transaction_type) 
from tabel1 
where name ='sam'
```

This will return a count of `2`, since there are only `2` *distinct* `transaction_type` values.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
select sum(amount)/count(distinct transaction_type) from tabel1 where name ='sam';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(amount) / COUNT(id)
FROM tabel1
WHERE
    name = 'sam'
GROUP BY
    transaction_type;
```